# When did the fifty-overs format for One-day international matches comes in practice?

Tags: cricket, history, officiating, icc

> In the early days of ODI cricket, the number of overs was generally 60
>   overs per side, and matches were also played with 40, 45 or 55 overs
>   per side, but now it has been uniformly fixed at 50 overs.
>    - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Day_International#Rules)

- What are all the over formats used in ODI history?
- When did the 50-overs format for one-day international matches comes
  in practice?

**Answer if possible,**

- How many matches were played for only 50-overs till now?

FYI, 5th ODI between Australia and England is the [3416th ODI match](http://www.espncricinfo.com/the-ashes-2013/engine/current/match/566945.html) in Cricket history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are all the over formats used in ODI history?

As already mentioned [40](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/64148.html), [45](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/64312.html), [55](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/64944.html), [60](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/65035.html), [50](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/64159.html) and [35](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/64150.html) overs.

> When did the 50-overs format for one-day international matches comes in practice?

I didn't find any source or article where it is mentioned. But I find it by reading scoreboards of ODI matches one by one from starting. The first 50 overs ODI was [West Indies v Pakistan](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/64159.html), ODI no. 41, played at Albion Sports Complex, Albion, Guyana in 16 March 1977.

Note that earlier in ODI format, the number of overs was not fixed. You can see scoreboard of [each ODI match by year here](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/307851.html).

---

#### Update:

Looking at [this post](http://www.quora.com/Cricket-sport/What-is-the-total-No-of-ODI-Played-with-60-Overs) it is clear that the ODI format of 50 overs per side came in practice from 1979/80 *in Australia* with colored cloths and day\night match. From that season *most* teams started following 50-overs format except England which continued playing 55-overs ODI *at home* until 1995. However, England also started playing 50-overs match at home from 1996 [v India](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/65017.html). From that 50-overs format remained in ODI.

Comment: Nice effort, but my question is not about first 50 overs match, it's abt `when did the overs got fixed to 50?` as you have mentioned that the overs were not fixed in the earlier days.

Comment: @SportsFan - I will try to answer your last question once I will get enough time to calculate. However it will be obsolete after a single ODI match is played. :)

Comment: Cricinfo might have the sorting option in statsguru page, but can't find that :(